# How to use EJBCA Web Services

Tags: java, api, token, ejbca

I'm writing a program which personalizes tokens.My end goal here is to find a way to get the required fields for the token from the CA. Is that possible and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by fields you mean certificate fields that are "required" in your configuration you can retrieve certificate and end entity profiles using the WS. Parsing them is a bit tricky, but you can find everything configured in the profiles there.

Comment: Thanks. If it's not asking for too much can you please give me an example of how you'd go about getting the certificate and end entity profiles with the WS?

Comment: You can find all methods from the WS API documentation. It's linked from the [Admin Guide](https://www.ejbca.org/docs/adminguide.html#EJBCA%20Web%20Service%20Interface)

In the [EjbcaWS](https://www.ejbca.org/docs/ws/org/ejbca/core/protocol/ws/client/gen/EjbcaWS.html), you can find the method getProfile, which gives you profile data.

if you can use this method, get back if you need help parsing the data.

Comment: Hi again.Turns out our version of Ejbca (6.2.0) doesn't have the getProfile ws but I was wondering if you'd be able to help with a different matter. I used apache cxf wsdl2js to generate a file with functions representing the WSs. If you're familiar with this way of using the ws can you please take a look at this http://pastebin.com/3Meq0hXg . I'm getting " org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Integer cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence" and I'm not sure how to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: That error sounds like it's something wrong with the CSR, and it can't be parsed. Try with the WS CLI first to ensure your input is correct, then use in your code.

Comment: Hi. Sorry yo bother you again but you seem to be the only one answer these types of questions. I posted another questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865299/how-to-delete-an-ejbca-end-entity-using-the-wss) about using the WSs about deleting end entities. If you can also shed some light on what a user data source is it would be great. I found some emails from 2008 answering this by linking a manual but it's 404 now. The responder was named Thomas so I guess it might have been you.

Comment: Hi again. Regarding parsing - I'm getting a profile (I think - here I think I have one http://pastebin.com/RZ7Et0be) but I'm really at a loss. Is there some sort of a table or a guide describing what integer points to what?

Comment: This diverges from the topic. Perhaps you should email to the ejbca mailing list instead?